# Error Handle in Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I saw a lot of post but I didn't understand how can I handle the error

I Have these middleware

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
```

And these middleware manage when I get 404 Page

Inside my routes I have for example:

```
app.route('/post/delete/:id_post')
    .get(function (req, res,next) {
        if(req.params.id_post !=req.decoded._id){
            var err = new Error('Error 500, you don\t have access');
            next(err);
        }

        Post.find({_id:req.params.id_post},function(err, post) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

How I have to manage error inside `if(req.params.id_post !=req.decoded._id)` and the error after Query on Db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware to catch error on routes like

```
app.get('/post/delete/:id_post',function(req,res,next){ 


    if(req.params.id_post !=req.decoded._id){
                var err = new Error('Error 500, you don\t have access');
                return next(err);
            }

            Post.find({_id:req.params.id_post},function(err, post) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            });

    },function(err,req,res,next){
       //you can handle all your errors thrown from ahead middleware
    })
```